# React Router v4 prevent from running parent route component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm building an article search with React [15.6.1] and Router [4.1.1] and noticed that when trying to access an article directly the previous component is loaded, even thou it's not the one that's being called

```
// === Layout ==================
class Layout extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={this.props.store}>
                <HashRouter>
                    <div>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={SearchFilter} />
                            <Route path="/article/:guid" component={Article} />
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </HashRouter>
            </Provider>
        );
    }

}

// === SearchFilter ==================
class SearchFilter extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('SearchFilter Did Mount');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>...</div>
        );
    }

}

// === Article ==================
class Article extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('Article Did Mount');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>...</div>
        );
    }

}
```

So when going to the root **localhost:3000/#/** it prints

```
// SearchFilter Did Mount
```

And when I access an article directly like this **localhost:3000/#/article/123456** it prints

```
// SearchFilter Did Mount
// Article Did Mount
```

So my question is, how can I prevent it from running the previous route?
Because I would like to dispatch some actions there that would trigger some ajax calls to the webservice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
<HashRouter basename="/">
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/search" component={SearchFilter} />
            <Route path="/article/:guid" component={Article} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</HashRouter>
```

Comment: Hi I was trying to avoid that because then I would have to redirect the root / to /search and when I do that the article just stops working

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

[image]

For me its working well... So like said... there is something really weird and hidden happening on your machine, or you just put / and then rewrite url to /#/article/123 and it cause the first log stays in the console, but its from the previsous url "/" and if you reload the browser by F5 on the new url /#/article/123 you will see only the "Article did mount"

Comment: Hi @Melounek that was a typo on my part. I'm using **//localhost:3000/#/**

Comment: I think you just have to refresh whole browser after typing the url, because for me its working fine.... (adding #/anythink... the browser will not reload)

Comment: The thing is once you access directly the article it should console.log only the **Article Did Mount** not both **Article Did Mount** and **SearchFilter Did Mount**

Comment: I am testing it and it is logging only "article did mount".... I thought you typed  "/" first and then if you rewrite the url to /#/article/123456 ... so in the console will stay the first message "searchFilter did mount" But if you are sure, this is not your case and you are really accessing this url from blank browser so itis weird

Comment: I was thinking more in terms if the user bookmarks the article, so he doesn't go through the search. And for me if I go directly there it's triggering both, hence question, if it would be possible to make route only load the article instead of both

Comment: oh that's really weird, it must be some wrong config on my app. gonna debug it to see what might be causing this problem. cheers mate